# Is SELECT * efficient than selecting particular columns?

Tags: mysql

I've come across a situation where i want to select almost all columns of the table except few. So which is better to use: SELECT * or selecting particular columns ? Can anyone brief this with respect to space and time efficiency.

Comment: How many rows do you have in your table? How many columns? What indexes? What table?

Comment: This horse has been beat too much.

Comment: I've heard that `SELECT *` is faster than `SELECT col1,col2,...colN` as well - even when selecting all columns in both examples. I personally, only specify the columns I need, though - if nothing else, to conserve the bandwidth of dealing with more data than I need.

Comment: I'm still in the developing stage testin with my own db... no of cols is 4, probably the rows may grow upto 10000. No exact idea